# SQL. Is count or limit more efficient for finding out whether a query returns N or more rows

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to find out whether a specific query (f.e.

```
Select * from data where time > 15000 and time < 30000
```

) returns less than 100 rows.

I could do:

```
Select count(*) from data where time > 15000 and time < 30000
if query.getSingleResult() < 100: ...
```

or

```
Select id from data where time > 15000 and time < 30000 limit 101
if query.getResultList().size() < 100: ...
```

Which is faster in which situation? I'd like to use the first one, but if there are billions of data points in that time-range, i'd guess the second one is faster.

Or is there a better, third way? preferable doable via jpa/hibernate.

Comment: could you explain why? from my understanding, the database needs to count all the records in the first way. At the second part, it just jumps to the first entry and reads 101 records and can stop. counting 1 billion sounds harder than reading 101.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to say.

The first query might be counting one row.  Or it might be counting one billion rows.  The second takes more time than the first.

The second query might be returning one row or 101 rows.  The second takes more time than the first.

In general, it is better to let the database do the work, which tilts the balance in favor of the first method.  On the other hand, the second might be slower for smallish data sets, but its performance is bounded.

What is the best method?  Try this:

```
select count(*)
from (Select id
      from data
      where time > 15000 and time < 30000
      limit 101
     ) d;
```

This should be the best of both worlds.  It returns only one row with one column.  And it should never read more than 101 rows from the table or view.

Comment: can you do this in jpa without native query?

Comment: I like that solution, but it seems to difficult with jpa as mentioned here:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/88 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555485/how-to-impose-limit-on-sub-query-of-jpa-query

Comment: You can with Blaze-Persistence. Scroll down past the accepted answer on that stackoverflow question.