# Java EE not compiling a query with the IN operator

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, join, ejb

I've written a query that works good if used into MySql Workbench, but it won't compile if used in my Java EE project!

Here's the query :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Book.findByCourse", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.teaching IN (SELECT T.id FROM Teaching T, Course C WHERE T.course = C.id AND C.id = :course)")
```

The query works fine, but I've got this error in my Java EE project :

> Error compiling the query [...], line 0, column 0: invalid IN expression argument [SubqueryNode
>     Left: null
>     Right: null], expected argument of type [entity.Teaching].

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, must ask: do you have the `Teacher` entity defined?

Comment: I've already done all the entities :)

Comment: Does the query compile if you replace `:course` with a constant value or a `?` (question-mark character) ?

Comment: Using `?` gives a parsing error, while using a constant value leads to the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are trying to select ids only in your subquery and then compare it to full pojo object (not sure if that's possible at all)

In my opinion you should either got with native query (@NamedNativeQuery) to achieve what you want or use Criteria Builder like for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions)