# JPA2 Criteria-API: select... in (select from where)

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, specifications

I have the following database model:

```
A
aId

AB
aId
bId

B
bId
status
```

In a Spring data Specification, I want to return the instances of A when B.status is 'X'.
The JPQL code is the following:

```
select a from A a where a in
     (select ab.id.a from AB ab where ab.id.b.status= :status)
```

These are the model classes:

```
@Entity
public class A {
     private Long aId;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.a")
     private Set<AB> ab;
}

@Entity
public class B {
     private Long bId;
     private String Status;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.b")
     private Set<AB> ab;
}

@Entity
public class AB {
     private ABPK id;
}

public class ABPK {
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="aId")
     private A a;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="bId")
     private B b;
}
```

How would be the JPA Criteria in the Spring Specification?

```
public class ASpecifications {
     public static Specification<A> test(final String status) {
          return new Specification<Party>() {
          @Override
          public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> a, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return null;
          }
        };
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Specification that returns instances of A using Criteria API is the following:

```
public class ASpecifications {
     public static Specification<A> test(final String status) {
          return new Specification<Party>() {
          @Override
          public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> a, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Subquery<A> sq = query.subquery(A.class);
            Root<AB> ab = sq.from(AB.class);
            sq.select(ab.get(AB_.id).get(ABPK_.a));
            sq.where(cb.equal(ab.get(AB_.id).get(ABPK_.b).get(B_.status), status));

            Predicate p = cb.in(a).value(sq);
            return cb.and(p);
          }
        };
     }
}
```

Comment: what is "a" here? cb.in(a).value(sq);

Comment: its the name of the Element Root<A> as you can see in the parameterlist of "toPredicate"

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples included on a previous post that address exactly what you're trying to accomplish here: [jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions).

Comment: Thank you codeturner. Unfortunately, the examples in that link don't help me with the embeddedId. In my case, I don't have the mapping attribute for the subQuery. I need aId, but ABPK has A, not aId.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted to select "A entities from AB entities where B is of provided status":

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<AB> ab = cq.from(AB.class);
cq.select(ab.get("id").get("a"));
cq.where(cb.equal(ab.get("id").get("b.status"), status));
```

Comment: Referring to the answer I provided with type safe. Thank you!

Comment: @Techky if this solves your problem you mentioned in the question, please accept this answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select In - is an option but you could achieve same result with double join. And its easier to make such a jpa specification:
`SELECT A.ID FROM A LEFT JOIN AB ON A.ID = AB.A_ID LEFT JOIN B ON AB.B_ID = B.ID WHERE B.STATUS = 'STATUS'`
Method would look like this:

```
public static Specification<A> findB(String input) {
    return new Specification<A>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Join<A,AB> AjoinAB = root.joinList(A_.AB_LIST,JoinType.LEFT);
            Join<AB,B> ABjoinB = AjoinAB.join(AB_.B,JoinType.LEFT);
            return cb.equal(ABjoinB.get(B_.NAME),input);
        }
    };
}
```

Or shorter

```
public static Specification<A> findB(String input) {
    return (Specification<A>) (root, cq, cb) -> {
        Join<A,AB> AjoinAB = root.joinList(A_.AB_LIST,JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<AB,B> ABjoinB = AjoinAB.join(AB_.B,JoinType.LEFT);
        return cb.equal(ABjoinB.get(B_.NAME),input);
    };
}
```

I know it's been a long time since this question arose, but I came across it when I tried to do the same. This is my solution that works and I hope it helps someone.

Entities below

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private List<AB> abList;
}
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String status;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
    private List<AB> abList;
}
@Entity
public class AB {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
}
```