# Build a search query with a search criteria in another table using JPA criteria

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I need to search states from `StateTable` based on a given country **name** (not `countryId`) in the `Country` table which should match the `like` SQL operator using JPA criteria API (`countryId` is the foreign key in `StateTable` as the name implies).

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder
                                          .createQuery(StateTable.class);
Root<StateTable>root=criteriaQuery.from(StateTable.class);

List<Predicate>predicates=new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
          .like(root.<String>get("countryName"), "%"+countryName+"%"));

criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
             .setFirstResult(first)
             .setMaxResults(pageSize)
             .getResultList();
```

How is the following statement to be modified to fulfill the need? (again `countryName` is available in the `Country` table and this criteria query is about `StateTable`).

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
          .like(root.<String>get("countryName"), "%"+countryName+"%"));
```

Using JPQL is tedious, since a query needs to be built for multiple search criterion. This is just a demonstration/illustration.

---

The `Country` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long countryId;             //<----------------------
    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "countryId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<StateTable> stateTableSet;
}
```

The `StateTable` entity:

```
@Entity
public class StateTable implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long stateId;
    @Column(name = "state_name")
    private String stateName;
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Country countryId;                //<-------------------------------
}
```

Comment: How have you defined the relationship between Country and StateTable? Anyway, the solution seems to require a join (both with JPQL and Criteria API)

Comment: Yes both of them have a relationship. `StateTable` has a foreign key which references to the primary key of `Country`.

Comment: In order to give the correct answer it's necessary to know how the relationship is defined in JPA. Please edit your question and add this information

Comment: Edited to add the entity classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to perform a join:

```
Join<StateTable, Country> country = root.join("countryId");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(country.<String>get("countryName"), "%"+countryName+"%"));
```

Comment: I was refering to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4668015/1391249) answer in between that uses a subquery but I'm unable to understand it because I have used the criteria API quite less frequently (indeed I have to study more on it). Generally, I use JPQL or (HQL with Hibernate) but here it is almost mandatory to use the criteria API. Your answer works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your criteria definition like (assuming that there is a property country in the State entity - in other words, assuming you have country_id as a foreign key in state table):

```
Join<StateTable, Country> country = root.join("country", JoinType.LEFT);

// and change predicate with 
predicates.add(cb.like(country.<String>get("countryName"), "%"+countryName+"%"));
```

This should do all the work.

Comment: There is a syntax error - `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method like(Path<String>,String)
  location: variable country of type Join<StateTable,Country>`, on the `like()` method.

Comment: It's criteriaBuilder.like(...)

Comment: With `criteriaBuilder.like(...)`, join is completely unused - `Join<StateTable, Country> country = root.join("country", JoinType.LEFT);` that throws an exception - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [countryName] against path`.

Comment: I just needed to replace `root` with `country` but I myself couldn't figure that out, sorry.