# JPA Criteria API Predicates for multiple requirements in child collection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

Consider the following scenario:

```
public class Parent {
    private List<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {
    private Target target;
    private Value value;
}

public class Target {
    private Long id;
}

public class Value {
    private Long id;
}
```

For every determined Target-object Parent-object will have Child-object that has Value-object.

I get filter in format of `HashMap<Long>, List<Long>>` where key is Target-object's id and value is list of desired Value-object id's.
What I need to get with JPA Criteria API is for example all Parents with following conditions:

- has child with targetId 1 with valueId in(1,2,3)
- AND has child with targetId 2 with valueId in(1,4)

So I need to exlude the results that dosen't meet all the requirements. Is there a way to achieve this with JPA Criteria API. I have tried the following:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
...
List<Predicate> subPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
Path<Child> child = root.join(Parent_.child, JoinType.LEFT);
for (Map.Entry<Long, List<Long>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Long targetId = entry.getKey();
    List<Long> valueIds = entry.getValue();
    subPredicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(child.get(Child_.target), targetId), child.get(Child_.value).in(valueIds)));
}
predicates.add(cb.and(subPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[subPredicates.size()])));
```

But obviously it doesn't work. Is this even possible with this kind of class structure?. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your approach seems fine. What's wrong with it? Include errors and/or query output. If it doesn't work, I'd try with a list of subqueries like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4668015/870122

Comment: Your question is confused. Are you passed a Map<Long, List<Long>> or are you passed a Map<Map<Long,List<Long>>, ?>. If the later, what is the value?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create two join, both with the child table, and setting a condition in each join, so if one of the two is not met, no result would appear.

For example:

```
Path<Child> childCondition1 = root.join(Parent_.child, JoinType.INNER);
Path<Child> childCondition2 = root.join(Parent_.child, JoinType.INNER);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.and([condition1 over childCondition1],[condition2 over childCondition2,]));
```

Another option (with JPA 2.1 in advance, probably more eficient):

```
Path<Child> childCondition1 = root.join(Parent_.child, JoinType.INNER);
    childCondition1.on([condition1 over childCondition1]);
Path<Child> childCondition2 = root.join(Parent_.child, JoinType.INNER);
    childCondition2.on([condition2 over childCondition2]);
```