# Cannot find entities not having an entity in a many to many relationship using a JPA Specification

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm looking to implement this query as a Specification for a Spring Data repository:

```
select * from Parts 
 where id not in (select partId 
                    from PartsToDeliveries
                    where deliveryId = 31)
```

(Basically, find all the parts that were not part of a certain delivery)

Here are the classes:

```
@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PartsToDeliveries", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "partId")}, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "deliveryId"))
    private Set<Delivery> deliveries = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Delivery {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "deliveries")
    private List<Part> parts;
}
```

Fill in the blank:

```
Specification<Part> specification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->     {
    ? _______ ?
}
```

I simply don't know where to start on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the similar semantics using `CriteriaAPI` - `CriteriaBuilder#not()` and `subquery()`

Here u have SO example of building similar query
[JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions)

and here are JPA docs http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

Antoniossss had the right lead to the solution (the doc not being particularly helpful).  For completeness here is the final solution:

```
specification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                Subquery<Long> subquery   = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
                Root<Part>     subFrom    = subquery.from(Part.class);
                Path<Long>     deliveryId = subFrom.join("deliveries").get("id");
                subquery.select(subFrom.get("id"));
                subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(deliveryId, 31l));

                Path<Long> id = root.get("id");
                return criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.in(id).value(subquery));
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
criteriaBuilder.not(root.get("deliveries").in(notWantedDelivery))
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph, but that created a SQL error. like: `and deliveries1_deliveryId=part2_.id and 1=1 and (. not in  (47))`.