# How to transform SQL (nested subquery) to query created by QueryBuilder

Tags: java, sql, jpa, query-builder

Is this possible to create a query by JPA QueryBuilder
using `query.from(subquery)`?

```
select DISTINCT substring(min(sel."order"), 2)
from
  (SELECT s.name || d.name "name",
          CASE
          WHEN d.status = 'ACCEPTED' then '0ACCEPTED'
          WHEN d.status = 'OPEN' then '1OPEN'
          WHEN d.status = 'DISMISSED' then '2DISMISSED'
          end "order"
   FROM items AS d
     LEFT JOIN store s ON d.store_id = s.id
   WHERE ... ) sel
GROUP BY sel.name
```

please don't try to see logic in the query

I just want to know how to create such construction by query builder

```
select * 
from (select something 
      from some table
      where conditions)
```

if it is possible of course

I know how to use a subquery in the WHERE or the SELECT section. but I don't know how to use subquery inside the FROM expression

Comment: What query builder are you talking about? JPA Criteria API?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli no, because I know how to use subquery in the WHERE or the SELECT section. but I don't know how to use subquery inside the FROM expression

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. You are right. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use plain SQL with Criteria API.

the Criteria API is working on the Entities not on the database tables.