# Spring Data Specification + subqueries

Tags: spring-data-jpa, subquery, specifications

I have a Measurements table like this:

```
                               Measurements 
 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________
|     id    |   created_at   | person_id  |  temperature |..... several columns with other values .... |
```

I want to use Spring Data Specification to query this table with dynamic list of search criteria. The challenge is that I want to get only the latest entries for each person_id that meet the search criteria. The query to get the latest results for each person can be something like this:

```
select *
from Measurements m
inner join (
    select person_id, max(created_at) as MaxDate
    from Measurements 
    group by person_id
) tm on p.person_id = tm.person_id and p.created_at = tm.MaxDate
```

How can I incorporate similar subquery to Specification with predicates for search criteria.

```
public static Specification<Measurements> findByCriteria(final SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {

        return new Specification<Measurements >() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Patient> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();


                if(searchCriteria.getTempMinLimit() != null) {

                    predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("temperature"), searchCriteria.getTempMinLimit()));    
                }

/*

other predicates

*/
```

OK so I have found that subquery can be placed only to the WHERE part of the query. I had to divide it into two queries in the end.

I am still confused about the toPredicate method parameters (public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {).

When I tried to call select on the query parameter nothing happened. Can I use the query parameter directly or I have to create a new query intance with the CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions)

Comment: Not completely I am curious about the integration of the Predicates and the subqueries in the Criteria API. The link you have send me only shows subqeury in Criteria API.