# Need a help for Spring JPA JPQL query to fetch multiple counts in single statement

Tags: spring

I need a help for similar query to use Spring JPA Custom query (JPQL) to fetch the multiple count results in single query as shown below.Below query framed in Mysql.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quiz  WHERE percentage is not null) as TotalCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quiz  WHERE percentage is not null and percentage  < 75) as LowerCount
```

Below are the results

```
TotalCount, LowerCount
'57',        '35'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions)

Comment: Hi Nikolai Shevchenko, It seems different. I am looking solution for having multiple count results in single query in JPQL.